# does not output character characteristics by overloading the output operator

Tags: c++

I have a Unit class and it has its own separate stats in a separate StateOfUnits class

Unit.h :

```
#ifndef UNIT_H
#define UNIT_H

#include "StateOfUnits.h"

class Unit {
public:
    StateOfUnits* state;
public:
    Unit(int PhyDamage,int hp, std::string state);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Unit& unit);

#endif //UNIT_H
```

Unit.cpp :

```
#include "Unit.h"

Unit::Unit(int phyDamage,int hp, std::string State) {
    state->setPhyDamage(phyDamage);
    state->setHp(hp);
    state->setState(State);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Unit& unit) {
    out << "Hp of " << unit.state->getState() << " : ";
    out << unit.state->getHP() << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

then StateOfUnits.h:

```
#ifndef STATEOFUNITS_H
#define STATEOFUNITS_H

#include <iostream>

class StateOfUnits{
public:
    int PhyDamage;
    int MagicDamage;
    int hp;
    std::string state;
public:
    int getHP() const;
    int getPhyDamage() const;
    int getMagicDamage() const;
    std::string getState() const;

    void setHp(int hp);
    void setPhyDamage(int dmg);
    void setMagicDamage(int dmg);
    void setState(std::string State);
};

#endif //STATEOFUNITS_H
```

in StateOfUnits.cpp the implementation is obvious, so I think that's enough only;

and main :

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Unit.h"
#include "StateOfUnits.h"

int main() {
Unit soldier(100, 100, "Soldier");

std::cout << soldier << std::endl;
}
```

I want to display the soladat's fields using operator overloading, but alas, it does not even display some kind of garbage, just nothing.

expected result :

```
Hp of soldier : 100
```

Comment: Change your `StateOfUnits* state;` for a `StateOfUnits state;`. Or, if you really want `state` to be a pointer to something in the heap, you should create it first (e.g. `make_unique` or `new` in `Unit` constructor).

Comment: Also, on a side note, the 2nd parameter of `operator<<` should be passed in by **const** reference (`const Unit&`)

Comment: but isn't a reference a constant pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
Unit::Unit(int phyDamage,int hp, std::string State) {
    state->setPhyDamage(phyDamage);
    state->setHp(hp);
    state->setState(State);
}
```

Your `state` variable is unassigned.